# Does std::vector::reserve reallocate the internal array?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a function which takes an `int *` and modifies the array that is passed in. I know ahead of time how many elements it will access. Let's say that's `m` values.

What will happen if I call `reserve(m)` on a `vector<int>` then send the pointer `data()` to the function?

My guess is that doing this *might* work if I subsequently access the data as though it were an array, from the pointer, but if I were to try to retrieve this data from the vector using `operator []` the size of the vector will not have been updated, and I will have issues. So I should just use `resize(m)` to do this.

Comment: Can you show us some code instead of explaining what the code does?

Comment: I'd say your guess is correct, just use `resize`.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, use resize(). Why do you even ask this, do you see any drawback on resize()?

Comment: `data()` is not a part of `std::vector` (2003 standard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it; it's undefined behaviour and simply not allowed. Instead, you should do the almost equally expensive `resize()` operation and then pass the `data()` pointer.

The only added cost comes from the zeroing out of the memory. Unfortunately there is no standard library container that handles *uninitialized* dynamic storage short of a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[m])`. The cost of the zeroing out is very small, though (but it may be conceptually annoying because you know that you are going to overwrite the data). I guess in a high-performance context you could give the unique-pointer approach a try. (Note that array-`new[]` for fundamental types is typically entirely equivalent to `::operator new()` or `malloc()`).

Answer (score 1):

Correct, `reserve(m)` on an empty vector simply guarantees that the next m `push_back()` will not trigger reallocation. The size of the vector will still remain 0 and writing to allocated data is forbidden.

Calling `resize(m)` is the correct way here.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reserve ( size_type n );
```

It only reallocates the internal array when the current capacity is less than *n* .

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` changes the internal size of the container (so that `capacity()` is now larger) but the `size` of the array doesn't grow any (`size()` remains the same as before the call). So, to directly answer your question, **yes**, it makes the `capacity` of the vector at least `n` where `n` is the parameter you gave to `reserve`.

I don't know if it's undefined behaviour to access beyond the end of a `vector` if the `capacity` is large enough (but `size` is less) when you call `data()` on it (or do `&v[0]`) and access the array through that pointer. I don't think it would be undefined behaviour as long as you're using POD types in the vector and don't read them before you write to them. Don't try this with class types though because the elements beyond the `size` of a vector will be uninitialised and using them *will* be UB.

It would be pointless to do this though, because then when you try to `push_back` something on the vector or call `resize` to actually update the size, it will overwrite the values you subversively wrote to the vector. Just use `resize` or use the `vector(int)` constructor to set the size on construction.

Comment: It should be undefined.  Those elements past `size()` aren't initialised.

Comment: @James he said he's using a `vector<int>` (POD), so as long as he doesn't read the values before writing them, he should be fine, no?

Comment: No, we're talking about an unresized vector.  Regardless of the templated type being stored, referencing (reading or writing) any element beyond the end of the vector is undefined.  (Effectively dereferencing end() + n, where n >= 0.)  While it might "work", it's definitely not good practice.

Comment: @James I think bad practice and undefined behaviour aren't the same thing. Whether or not this is good practice is fairly obvious (it's not), but I don't think that makes it undefined behaviour.

Comment: To be honest, having just spent the last 20 minutes looking through the C++ standard I can't tell if it is undefined or not.  My gut instinct still says it is, or if it isn't it should be.  The only way to access a vector's memory is through `&*`, which creates a pointer, and obviously if you know the memory is valid, incrementing and dereferencing that pointer is not undefined.  However, the fact it's a pointer obtained through dereferencing an iterator there's a slightly grey area here: `( &*begin() ) + n` isn't undefined, but `&*( begin() + n )` is (where n >= size() and n < capacity().)

Comment: @James if anyone knows, it's KerrekSB, I'll ask him on his answer.

Comment: The only way it can *not* be UB is if you can show where it is defined. Talking informally about what you expect the implementation to do doesn't count for anything. If the standard defines the behavior, it is well-defined. Otherwise it is not. And the only way to show that the standard defines it is to quote it.

Comment: @James the guys in the Lounge<C++> chatroom have explained why this is in fact UB, you can read it if you are interested.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, thanks for digging into this. I will summarize JohannesSchaublitb's comments from chat: "the implementation coudl rely on special OS system calls that guarantee contiguous storage upon special other function calls -- say, the implemtation locks 5 pages for you. but to be able to write to the second page, it first needs to mark it writable -- if you now think "ah a reserve is enough", it might not be because the other 4 pages are still read only" This is a great example: we should never assume anything (e.g. the data is writeable) about the implementation which isn't guaranteed!